# Creating labels for maps, made with ggplot in R

Tags: r, label, mapping, r-sf

I've got a question about how to make labels for my map and how to make a legend for this labels.
For example, I have an `sf` object containing info about 55 NY subboroughs, which looks like:

```
           SUBBOROUGH                       geometry Spending_per_capita_all        brks ID
1             Astoria MULTIPOLYGON (((592483.9 45...            0.2299462931       0.1-1  1
2           Bay Ridge MULTIPOLYGON (((582292.3 44...            0.0084253956  0.006-0.01  2
3 Bayside/Little Neck MULTIPOLYGON (((607770.6 45...            0.0012083661 0.001-0.003  3
4  Bedford Stuyvesant MULTIPOLYGON (((589322.6 45...            0.0238263409   0.01-0.05  4
5         Bensonhurst MULTIPOLYGON (((585215.6 44...            0.0009825423      <0.001  5
...
```

I want to make a map with ggplot, lets simplify like that:

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = sub_boroughs_morning_rides, aes(fill = brks))
```

In the resulting map (on image below, this is more complicated one) I want to have labels in the center of each polygon, representing the ID of an appropriate subborough (the "ID" field already contains this ID value). I also want these ID to be explained in a legend like: 1 - Astoria, 2 - Bay Bridge and so on.

[current_map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZTDF.png)

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For listing IDs in center of your polygons consider `ggplot2::geom_sf_text()` call, like the example bellow; for explaining the legend I suggest to do this outside of R / RStudio.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

ggplot(data = shape) +
   geom_sf() + # polygon of North Carolina
   geom_sf_text(aes(label = CNTY_ID)) # labels
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will try!