# How to add the zipcode labels and/or refrence map to a map made with zip_choropleth

Tags: r, choroplethr

I want to make a simple chloropleth map which shows the count for a value by zipcodes in a county. I feel like there must be a simple way to do this, I have a working function below that makes the map I want it to make everything is perfect aside from a lack of labels for zipcodes but I cant find anything on the internet on how to simply add the zipcode labels

df has a col for regions (zipcodes) and a col for value (a count for each zipcode)

```r
zip_choropleth(df, county_zoom = X, title = "Title", legend = "legend", num_colors = 1) + coord_map()
```

Alternatively I could add a reference map to give it some context but
I tried using `reference_map = TRUE` like in the link below but that no longer seems to work!

https://rdrr.io/github/arilamstein/choroplethrZip/man/zip_choropleth.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating labels for maps, made with ggplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64466559/creating-labels-for-maps-made-with-ggplot-in-r)

Comment: No unfortunately it does not I dont have shape files I am using the zip_choropleth package which loads:

> head(zip.regions)
  region state.name county.name county.fips.numeric  cbsa cbsa.title
1  70560  louisiana      iberia               22045 10020       <NA>
2  70510  louisiana   vermilion               22113 10020       <NA>

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example? It's difficult to help if we don't know what format your data is in.

Comment: As @nrennie wrote, having code is necessary to provide help on what may be happening, as well as any data that you are using.